# What is the most efficient way print first K digits of a factorial without calculating the whole factorial?

Tags: python-3.x

My `K` has to be around 15,
and the number of which i am tring to get first k of its factorial is ~10^9.

Essentially I need to compute first 15 digits of `n!` where <= 1000000000 in under a second or so.

Everyone says its easy in python but I am still not able to .
My attempt using [Stirlings approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is only printing first 4 digits correctly. Let alone efficiency. :'(

```
import * from decimal
import *from math
getcontext().prec = 100

n = int(input())

x = Decimal("10") ** Decimal(str(Decimal(str(n)) * Decimal(str(n)).log10() - Decimal(str(n)) * Decimal(e).log10()))
print(x * Decimal(Decimal("2") * Decimal(str(n)) * Decimal(pi)).sqrt())
```

Tried increasing  precision of `Decimal` more but doesnt make any difference.

Comment: Does your Sterling approximation work for smaller numbers?  For example what happens if n = 1000, 10000?

Comment: @itprorh66 only first 4 digits.